# How can I enable/restore left sidebar for setting margin in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice

I still have top sidebar that allows to easily change margins.

But something happened with left one.

How can I restore it? I tried deleting settings, it have not helped.

LibreOffice 7.2.5.2 on Lubuntu 20.04.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> But something happened with left one.

The "left one" is the vertical ruler. The top one is the horizontal ruler.

> How can I restore it?

To view/restore the vertical ruler, click on View -> Ruler -> Vertical Ruler

[image: Settings to view the vertical ruler]